# accept outlook invitation (.ics attachment) without MS software

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, icalendar

My problem: one of our customers wants us to accept their appointments by using icalendar .ics MS outlook generated attachments. We need to reply with another .ics attachment, so that his (ms exchange?) system records our acceptance. We have no MS software in the company, do not use Google or Yahoo calenders, and this is needed rarely, once a month or so.

Ideally, I would prefer a web based service where I can paste their .ics formula (starting with VCALENDER...) and generate a reply which I will send as an attachment from mutt. Another possibility is a command line script which I can apply from within mutt directly.

Answer (score 2):

you would need to send the answer according to the RFC 6047 ([here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6047#section-1.1) for the full length)

to give you an idea of what the RFC states, see below:

2. MIME Message Format Binding

This section defines the message binding to the MIME electronic mail
transport.

The sections below refer to the "originator" and the "recipient" of
an iMIP message.  In the case of a "request" method, the originator
is the "Organizer" and the recipient is an "Attendee" of the event.
In the case of a "response" method, the originator is an "Attendee"
and the recipient is the "Organizer" of the event.

The [RFC5322] "Reply-To" header field typically contains the email
address of the originator of the scheduling message.  However, this
cannot be guaranteed because the sender of the iMIP message might not
be the originator of the scheduling message and the sender's "Mail
User Agent" (MUA) might not enforce iMIP semantics by translating the
originator's address into the "Reply-To" email header field.